# How to git revert the changes of one specific file, while my commits changes are involving other files as well?

Tags: git

**Case Scenario**

Let's assume that I have 3 files:

```
 Dir/
     a.py
     b.py
     c.py
```

and I have 10 commits, each one of which is involving changes to ALL of those three files.

> For example commit with hash code ABCD is changing 3 lines from **a**, 10 lines from **b** and 1 line from **c**. Same stands for the rest for the commits.

At that point I am realizing that ALL the changes have been made in file *a.py* are useless.

1. How can I revert ALL the changes of file *a.py* WITHOUT reverting my changes in the other two files?
2. And what is the best practice to approach this kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do: `git checkout <commit_hash> -- <file>`.

It will reset this specific file to the specified commit.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue